# How we can rename a list of built-in administrator accounts to "administrator"? (using vbs)

Tags: windows, vbscript, admin, built-in

I'm trying to change all the built-in windows local administrators names in my domain.
The new name will be "administrator", but it seems that my script is unable to read the  excel data(server|old account name).

```
DIM strPassword, strAdminUserName, strNewAdminUserName

Dim strExcelPath, objExcel, objSheet, intRow


'''''
'Spreadsheet file.
strExcelPath = "c:\List.xls"

' Bind to Excel object.
On Error Resume Next
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Wscript.Echo "Excel application not found."
    Wscript.Quit
End If
On Error GoTo 0

' Open spreadsheet.
On Error Resume Next
objExcel.Workbooks.Open strExcelPath
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Wscript.Echo "Spreadsheet cannot be opened: " & strExcelPath
    Wscript.Quit
End If
On Error GoTo 0

' Bind to worksheet.
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)



intRow = 2
Do While objSheet.Cells(intRow, 1).Value <> ""
    comp = objSheet.Cells(intRow, 1).Value
    strAdminUserName = objSheet.Cells(intRow, 2).Value
    strNewAdminUserName = "Administrator"   
On Error Resume Next



' Rename a local user account on a given computer

    SET objComputer = GetObject("WinNT://" & Comp)
    SET objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & Comp & "/" & strAdminUserName & ",user")
    IF err.number = 0 THEN
        objComputer.MoveHere objUser.ADsPath,strNewAdminUserName
    END IF
    ON ERROR GOTO 0
loop

' Close the workbook.
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

' Quit Excel.
objExcel.Application.Quit

Wscript.Echo "Done"
```

Any opinion/comment will be appreciated.

Comment: This seems quite an odd approach, however, which line of your code does it fail on?

Comment: I end-up killing excel process and getting this error : C:\script.vbs(41, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable: 'Cells'

Comment: You end-up killing the Excel, that is what will trigger the VBS error, are you able to debug the Excel VBA and see which part the code seems to hang on?

Comment: In your Do-While loop, try printing the value of your variables: 'wscript.echo "comp=" & comp', and do same for the other two variables. Without that info and the xls sheet, can't tell what's wrong. Debug with those lines and it will tell you helpful info.